# Как перезапустить / полностью обновить ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Имеется обычный `ViewController`, и его `self.view` добавлено 10-15 обычных `view`.
Как после того, как с этими `view` выполнены все действия (их перемещение в рамках `ViewController` - a), обновить `ViewController`, вернув его к начальному состоянию, в принципе, даже ничего сохранять не нужно.

Метод `setNeedsDisplay`, отвечающий за перерисовку `view` как-то не срабатывает.
А вызывать `viewDidLoad` - наверное, не самое лучшее решение

Comment: а что именно имеется ввиду под начальным состоянием? убрать все эти view?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, Здравствуйте! Я имею ввиду возвращение всех view в исходное положение на self.view. Естественно, без анимации. Как бы "рестарт" ViewController -a.

Comment: вам просто надо вынести установку фреймов в отдельный метод из метода `viewDidLoad` и вызывать его при необходимости перерисовки. Для более полного ответа мне надо увидеть содержимое метода `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2):

У UIView есть свойство subviews, что представляет собой NSArray.
Поэтому для решения вашей задачи нужно пробежаться по всем subviews и вызвать removeFromSuperview для каждой.

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Если нужно восстановить позицию на вью после перемещения, то сохраните локации всех сабвьюх в архив а потом восстановите

```
//сохранить
NSMutableArray *subViewFramesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
    [subViewFramesArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:subView.frame]];
}

//восстановить
int i = 0;
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
    [subView setFrame:[[subViewFramesArray objectAtIndex:i] CGRectValue]];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: в комментарии к вопросу, автор указал, что надо не убрать view, а вернуть в начальное положение

Comment: в таком случае вам нужно хранить frame каждого subView в массиве и потом восстановить все примерно так

Answer (score 0):

Предложу просто создать viewController заново и заменить текущий новым.

Если у вас один контроллер:

```
ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = myViewController;
```

если у вас иерархия управляемая navigationController'ом:

```
ViewController *myViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
```